# How Settings.Default work for multiple applications accessing same dll

Tags: c, wpf, dll, application-settings

I have two applications refering to a dll (A.dll). The dlls are refernced from both application's local directories. Application1 use Settings.Default to store string to the dll (A.dll). Will those strigs that are saved to settings of A.Dll by Applciation1 be accessible to Application2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, each application setting should have it's own settings file. Furthermore, if you have used a user-scoped settings, then each *user* from each application will have their own settings files.

You can find full details from the following links:

[Using Settings in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

[Application Settings Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0.aspx)